# Scripting SSH function getting `Connection refused` error

Tags: shell-script, stdin, fish

I am using `fish` as shell, `ssh` shortcut function as following:

```
function sshec2
  ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/key.pem -t -t "ubuntu@$argv[1]"
end
```

To ssh into specific AWS EC2 instance, I wrote command pipe flow:

```
ec2-describe-instances --region us-west-2 --filter "tag:Name=test-box" |
grep 'INSTANCE' |
grep -E -m 1 -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'|
head -1 |
sshec2
```

However I got an error `ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused`, while `sshec2` function works when I run `sshec2 <ec2_public_ip>`.

Any stupid part I am missing?

Comment: `ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused` looks like you are missing the hostname on the command-line. What do you get if your put `echo "$argv[1]"` into the `sshec2` function? And what if your remove the `| sshec2` from the end of the other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a pipeline that generates a list of host names (`ec2-describe-instances … | grep … | grep …`), you take the first line (`head -1`), and you want to use that as the host name to connect to. You're passing the host name on the standard input of the `sshec2` function and calling the function with no argument. So when the function is executed, `$argv[1]` is empty, and you end up running `ssh` with the arguments `-i`, `/home/dearrrfish/.ssh/key.pem`, `-t`, `-t`, `ubuntu@`. If you ended up with a valid `ssh` command line and the connection did go through, then the output of the `… | head -1` pipeline would be piped into the program that `ssh` runs.

You need to pass the host name as the first argument to the function instead. The tool for that is [command substitution](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_command_substitutions).

```
sshec2 (ec2-describe-instances --region us-west-2 --filter "tag:Name=test-box" |
        grep 'INSTANCE' |
        grep -E -m 1 -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' |
        head -1)
```